# Wrangling dataframes with Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I'm trying to find a neat Dplyr solution to convert this dataframe;

```
Rule <- c('Rule 1', 'Rule 1', 'Rule 1', 'Rule 1', 'Rule 2', 'Rule 2', 'Rule 2')
Condition <- c('1 of 4', '2 of 4', '3 of 4', '4 of 4', '1 of 3', '2 of 3', '3 of 3')
Clause <- c('Temperature > 60', 'Temperature < 90', 'Rain = 0', 'Wind < 20', 'Temperature > 55', 'Temperature < 85', 'Rain <= 2')
Lift <- c('1.30', '1.30', '1.30', '1.30', '1.60', '1.60', '1.60')
Coverage <- c('20%','20%','20%','20%','35%','35%','35%')
DF <- data.frame(Rule, Condition, Clause, Lift, Coverage)
```

Into this dataframe;

```
Rule <- c('Rule 1', 'Rule 1', 'Rule 1', 'Rule 1','', 'Rule 2', 'Rule 2', 'Rule 2')
Condition <- c('1 of 4', '2 of 4', '3 of 4', '4 of 4','', '1 of 3', '2 of 3', '3 of 3')
Clause <- c('Temperature > 60', 'Temperature < 90', 'Rain = 0', 'Wind < 20','', 'Temperature > 55', 'Temperature < 85', 'Rain <= 2')
Lift <- c('', '', '', '1.30', '','', '', '1.60')
Coverage <- c('','','','20%','','','','35%')
Result <- data.frame(Rule, Condition, Clause, Lift, Coverage)
```

Notice new blank rows which separates rules and repetitive Lift and Coverage metrics have been removed. Only retaining the Lift and Coverage from the final row of each rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a blank row to insert in every `Rule` :

```
empty_df <- data.frame(matrix('', nrow = 1, ncol = ncol(DF), 
                       dimnames = list(NULL, names(DF))))
```

Split the data for each unique `Rule`, replace the repeating values in `Lift` and `Coverage` column with blank add `empty_df` and combine the result.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  group_split(Rule) %>%
  purrr::map_df(~.x %>% 
        mutate(across(c(Lift, Coverage), 
              ~replace(., duplicated(., fromLast = TRUE), ''))) %>%
        bind_rows(empty_df)
        ) %>%
  #Remove the blank row from last `Rule`. 
  slice(-n())

#    Rule     Condition Clause             Lift   Coverage
#  <chr>    <chr>     <chr>              <chr>  <chr>   
#1 "Rule 1" "1 of 4"  "Temperature > 60" ""     ""      
#2 "Rule 1" "2 of 4"  "Temperature < 90" ""     ""      
#3 "Rule 1" "3 of 4"  "Rain = 0"         ""     ""      
#4 "Rule 1" "4 of 4"  "Wind < 20"        "1.30" "20%"   
#5 ""       ""        ""                 ""     ""      
#6 "Rule 2" "1 of 3"  "Temperature > 55" ""     ""      
#7 "Rule 2" "2 of 3"  "Temperature < 85" ""     ""      
#8 "Rule 2" "3 of 3"  "Rain <= 2"        "1.60" "35%"
```